# Terminology for a function being odd/even about a line

Tags: real-analysis, terminology

Is there a name for when a function is odd about an x coordinate other than zero? For example, sine is odd about $x=0$, but also $x=\pi$ i.e. $\sin(\pi+x)=-\sin(\pi+-x)$. However, describing this as "odd about x=pi" seems unconventional as the wikipedia definition of odd implies symmetry about the origin.

Comment: An odd function may be described as a function which is symmetric about the origin.  Perhaps you could describe such a function as symmetric about a given point (e.g. $\sin(x)$ is symmetric about $(0,\pi)$.